# Как прикрутить прокрутку для табов (вкладок) на Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html5, css3, bootstrap

Сверстал табы Bootstrap в виде таблицы, теперь нужно их адаптивить, но при уменьшении размера экрана

[image: расширение 480px]

табы наезжают друг на друга, что выглядит просто ужасно.

Как вариант предложили `overflow-x: scroll;`, но куда его прицепить, чтобы правильно сработало, и табы были с прокруткой при уменьшении экрана?

[проект](http://martynuk.info/index_price.html)

Comment: а задать размеры в vw и шрифт тоже - вариант ? и без самой разметки не ясно

Comment: разметка есть, виложыл проект

Comment: табы не рабочие же там - при клике не работает смена

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZRMMR?editors=110  вот табы на чистом css - я сам написал - посмотри - не проблемно

Comment: спасибо, но насчет не рабочих табов это вы пошутили, все рабочее. А касательно моего вопроса, то проблема не в создании табов, они созданы и работают, но вот при малых расширениях смотрятся криво, и мне интересно как это можно поправить.

Comment: почему не рабочие ? всё там работает - а на счёт криво - вы бы всё таки показали бы разметку , могу вам и по советовать что не будь

Answer (score 1):

На табы можно повесить карусель, к примеру, [liquidcarousel](http://www.nikolakis.net/liquidcarousel/). В случае, если они не будут помещаться в заданную область, появятся стрелки для их прокрутки.